# how to run an application with a command in terminal from all users

Tags: command-line

I made a command for a user user1 so when i write in terminal `cool-retro-term` it runs the application

If I switch user to user2 and I try to run `cool-retro-term` or `sudo cool-retro-term` it says `the command not found`

I want to know how to make the command usable for all users.  Until now I installed and compiled the application like they said. then i made a bash script in `/home/user1/bin` where i added

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/user1/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term
```

to run my application

I modified .bashrc `PATH=$PATH:/home/crs/bin` and then I ran `chmod u+x /home/crs/bin/cool-retro-term`

```
I EDITED my question
```

i want to make my command something like `ls` or `cd` or other command usable for all users. something like that . ANY IDEAS?

Comment: It would be cool, if you would upvote the posts and comments of the question, that helped you do that in the first place..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file over to a directory that is in everyone's `$PATH`. You can check the path with `echo $PATH`. This should be a default path:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

My suggestion would be the bin directory in local. So that would be

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Avoid general bin directories like /bin, /usr/bin, /sbin and /usr/sbin. Keep those directories clean so you know where your system files and your personal files are.

---

I would also advice something else: if possible (ie. those users are similar in permissions) you can also add both users to the same group. That way permisssions for one also apply to the other.

Comment: i moved like you said in `/usr/local/bin`  but it still says that i can't execute with `user2`

Comment: Check the permissions of the file and make sure user2 is included in those permissions; adding user2 to the same group as user1 is the best method ;)

Comment: and is a command to make permissions for all user in one time? or i need to edit the permision for each user?

Comment: Maybe you need to `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cool-retro-term`

Answer (score 1):

Move everything from `/home/crs/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`.

Be aware, you need to be root to do that.

Comment: i moved it , and if i run with `user2` it says `Sorry, user user2 is not allowed to execute '/bin/cool-retro-term' as root`

Comment: Please don't use /bin ;)

Comment: Answer came up in the low-quality queue, so I edited it.